# Does Mach semaphore work in shared memory between processes?

Tags: c, macos, ipc, semaphore, shared-memory

I'm interested in using a semaphore, created using `semaphore_create(task, sem, policy, value)` from `mach/semaphore.h`, in a shared memory to synchronize two processes in Mac OS.

I know that on Linux using `sem_init(sem, pshared, value)`, `pshared` has to be non-zero in this case, however I cannot find and information on Mac (where `sem_init` is not implemented), and I do not really want to use named semaphores as I will need to create a lot of them.

I experimented on a minimal example and it does not seem to work, so I'm wondering if I did something wrong or it just doesn't work. I'm also open to other inter-process lock alternatives.

Comment: [Here](http://pkaudio.blogspot.de/2010/05/mac-os-x-no-timed-semaphore-waits.html) is an article on how to share a Mach semaphore between processes. Note that you should really try to avoid using Mach stuff as its usage in userland is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

OSX does not support anonymous semaphores. The function calls are implemented to get posix compliance but if you check the return codes they actually error out with an unimplemented error. I wrote a post with more details on OSX and unnamed semaphores here, along with a suggested solution:
[Unnamed-semaphores-and-pososx](http://ck-hack.blogspot.com/2013/09/unnamed-semaphores-and-pososx.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the documentation on semaphore_create and friends:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/synchronization/synchronization.html

I don't own a Mac, so I can't test anything out, but I don't see any reason why unnamed semaphores aren't possible.